# Group Files by Name in SharePoint Library

Tags: sharepoint

I’m creating a library on SharePoint 2013. All my files are Excel files and have names with two first letters specifying a type of the document (for example **TE**.example.xlsx is **Template** type and **FO**.next_example.xlsx would be **Form** and so on).

I wanted to group the files by these first two letters but it’s actually impossible to refer to the column Name (when grouping or creating a calculated column). Is there a way to group these files like that without creating a workflow?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: how many types of documents do you have (2,3 or n)? You can add new Choice field with all that types (Form, Template and so on) and write powershell which will get names for each document and update choice field. Then you set that choice filed required for later use.

Comment: I was hoping that it's possible to avoid workflows, powershell etc. and do it only with the options available in the basic user interface but I'm afraid that's not possible since I want this to be kind of automated. I guess I'm just stuck with subfolders ;)